# Is there a way to only show the first date of a 5 day streak?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, gaps-and-islands, mysql-5.7

What I want is to show the first date of a 5 day streak, if it is a total of 10 days it counts as 2 streaks. The range of months can be set specifically only once. For example: I want to get all the available dates from the month of Jan. 2023-01-01 => 2023-01-31.

For example:

My Table:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 |
| 1 | 2023-01-04 |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 |
| 1 | 2023-01-06 |
| 1 | 2023-01-07 |
| 1 | 2023-01-08 |
| 1 | 2023-01-09 |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 |
| 1 | 2023-01-15 |
| 1 | 2023-01-16 |

Output:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | 2023-01-06 |

What I am hoping to ultimately achieve from this output:

| id | streak |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

**What I have tried**
I tried using counters but they are expensive and I tried filtering out days with no continuous dates after but it also takes out the very last day of a streak.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    a.id AS id,
    a.date as DATE
FROM 
    logins a,
    (SELECT @counter := 0, @streak := 0) counter,
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT(b.date) as date
        FROM 
            logins b
        WHERE
            b.id = 1 AND
            b.date >= '2023-01-01' AND
            b.date  <= '2023-01-31'
    ) b
WHERE 
    a.id = 1 AND
    a.date >= '2023-01-01' AND
    a.date <= '2023-01-31' AND
    DATE_ADD(a.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) = b.date AND
    b.date BETWEEN a.date AND DATE_ADD(a.date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY
    id, date
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with variables:

- @prev_date, that will check for successive values of date
- @counter, that will check for reaching 5 consecutive values, then restart
- @partition, that will check be updated when @counter reaches 1 again

Once you update the values of these variables correctly, you can run an aggregation on each partition (thanks to @partition) and selecting the minimum date that satisfy the count of consecutive days = 5.

```
SET @prev_date = NULL;
SET @counter = 1;
SET @partition = 0;

SELECT id, MIN(date_) AS date_
FROM (SELECT id,
             CASE WHEN @prev_date =  date_ - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND @counter < 5 
                  THEN @counter := @counter + 1
                  ELSE @counter := 1 
             END AS counter,
             IF(@counter = 1, @partition := @partition + 1, @partition) AS parts,
             @prev_date := date_ AS date_
      FROM tab) cte
GROUP BY id, parts
HAVING COUNT(parts) = 5
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mYJsX63FqTsu15ezSZSMnb/0).

Comment: Yo thanks! I'll try it and come back to you!

Comment: It works! But can you help me with one issue, when there is a duplicate date in the database it seems to mess this query up how would I go about solving that bug?

Comment: Can you update your sample data with this specific corner case and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: Nvm figured it out. But since it is unrelated to the question I am just gonna choose your answer since it answered my original question.